# Create cross-tabulation in python pandas showing which values are present

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation, crosstab

given the following data:

```py
pd.DataFrame(dict(
    name = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
    vals = [1, 2 , 3, 99, 3, 4]
))
```

which looks as:

```
  name  vals
0    a     1
1    a     2
2    a     3
3    b    99
4    b     3
5    b     4
```

I'm wondering how to create the following:

```
     1     2    3      4     99
a  true  true  true  false  false
b  false false true  false  true
```

Note - having the exact values of `true` and `false` in the above aren't so important, I don't know how to go about creating a table of this type at the moment.

Comment: The function exists in pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html

Answer (score 6):

Try this `crosstab`

```
s=pd.crosstab(df.name,df.vals).astype(bool)
Out[38]: 
vals     1      2     3      4      99
name                                  
a      True   True  True  False  False
b     False  False  True   True   True
```

Answer (score 2):

Could also `get_dummies` and then aggregate along the `names`

```
pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('name').vals).any(level=0) 
                                        #.max(level=0) for 1/0 dummies
                                        #.sum(level=0) for counts
```